# Boolean Simplification: (A+C)(!A+B)(B+C) = BC

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, propositional-calculus

How might I solve this? I can't find any problem similar to this, and I always end up with the wrong terms.

If (AB) = 0 and (A+B) = 1, prove that (A+C)(!A+B)(B+C) = BC

Comment: I've removed [tag:algebra] tag, since we don't use algebra tag anymore, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/473/the-use-of-the-algebra-tag/3081#3081) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding the LHS is D=BC(A+!A+1)+!AC+AB=(B+!A)C+(AB). Since A+B=1 and AB=0, !A=B hence B+!A=B and D=(BC)+(AB). Once again, AB=0 hence D=BC.

Comment: Can you explain "Since A+B=1, B+!A=B"? What is the logic in this statement?

Comment: @user1764389: $A + B = 1$ and $AB = 0$ implies that $A = !B$.  Hence, $B + !A = B + B = B$.

Answer (score 0):

did's answer is the way to go in general.  However, notice that for your problem, $AB = 0$ and $A +B = 1$ implies that either $A = 1$ and $B = 0$ or $A = 0$ and $B = 1$.

In the first case, $BC = (B + !A) = 0$, and so the two sides are equal.

In the second case, we have

$$
(A +C)(!A + B)(B + C) = (C)(1)(1) = C = BC
$$